# Increment input name and ID when it is inserted in the dom

Tags: jquery

how can I increment the input name and ID each time the element is inserted in the dom,

```
<input type="text" name="option_tree[sponsorship_section][1][image1]" id="sponsorship_section_image1_1">
```

to this:

```
<input type="text" name="option_tree[sponsorship_section][1][image2]" id="sponsorship_section_image1_2">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to the element. In jQuery count the elements and store length in variable then you can use that variable to increment and insert in the DOM.